# How can I make Perl die if a warning is generated?

Tags: perl, warnings, die

I would like my script perl to die whenever a warning is generated, including warnings which are generated by used packages.

For example, this should die:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Statistics::Descriptive;

my @data = ( 8, 9, 10, "bbb" );
my $stat = Statistics::Descriptive::Full->new();
$stat->add_data(@data);
```

`use warnings FATAL => 'all';` won't help since it's lexically scoped. [Test::NoWarnings](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-NoWarnings/) also doesn't do the work since it doesn't kill the script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add to rafl's answer: when adding a handler to `%SIG`, it is (usually) better to not overwrite any previous handler, but call it after performing your code:

```
my $old_warn_handler = $SIG{__WARN__};
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub {

    # DO YOUR WORST...

    $old_warn_handler->(@_) if $old_warn_handler;
};
```

(This also applies to signal handlers like `$SIG{HUP}`, `$SIG{USR1}`, etc. You
never know if some other package (or even another instance of "you") already
set up a handler that still needs to run.)

Comment: This is the better approach... Just like C, the signals need to cooperate and cascade or you will have unintended actions at a distance modifying global handlers with a single value.

Answer (score 19):

I believe you're looking for `$SIG{__WARN__}` as documented in [`perlvar`](http://p3rl.org/perlvar). Something similar to

```
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { die @_ };
```

might be what you want.

Comment: But note that you're changing a global and might see unintended consequences.  It would probably be a good idea to audit the packages you use for modifications to `$SIG{__WARN__}`.